# How do you solve long tail problem in a recommendation system?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cluster-analysis, recommendation-engine

I want to make a movie recommendation system using the binary ratings that is whether a person has seen the movie or not! I am using various cosine similarity techniques and all but the issue is the **Long Tail
in Recommendation System**. I am not able to find any concrete solution which uses just viewed or not (i.e. either 0 or 1) and not the ratings as such for the recommendation? What other popular algorithms can be used for the same. I need to remove the long tail issue,

- I have used *Adaptive Clustering* but it needs many Derived Variables and those are not present here.
- Used other ways like *Total Clustering* but no use.
- Used *Popularity Sensitive Clustering* but same issue.

Been stuck here in this long tail issue but not getting even a good implementation for my work or a research paper that helps but nothing.

Everyone is using either ratings or the user data but my work doesn't have any user info and neither is it having any ratings just the binary values.

Answer (score 2):

The `Long Tail` issue in recommendation systems basically is about how to give users recommendation of items that do not have a lot of interactions(ratings/likes) etc. As similarity algorithms like `cosine similarity` and `clustering algorithms` fails in recommending them. You need to look into `diversity` increasing algorithms.

What I mean is rather than calculating `similarity` try calculating `dissimilarity`.

[image]

Here `R` is recommendation list, `d(i, j)` is dissimilarity.

You can use [surprise](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to generate `R` here using `matrix factorization` algorithms.

Also, when you generate a `user` vs. `item` matrix where `matrix[user_i][item_j]` denote rating you can convert it to `1` to show rating and `0` otherwise and it will still work. Also, these binary ratings generally are call interaction the user had with the item.